# How to automate azure boards?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I have features which need to be assigned to the design team , then the backend team and finally for test and publish of the application.
with the current setup , everyone is in one team and they just drag and drop their work to the next column. 
could someone help me please set this automation up ?

i have tried adding more swimlanes and adding more columns but it just makes a mess and is not as tidy and user friendly as it should be. 
also i do not wish to duplicate all the items for all the teams all over again as it will go over 3000 features and i do not have the time to sort everything all over again.

i wish to know how long it took for the backend and front end as well as testing , then decide how to move forward with each team.
more over once i add a new feature or an epic , and assign it to the design team , they should be able to assign it to the backend team , then to the front end and so forth. neither should be able to drag it to Done unless it has gone through the team thats is responsible for the launch of the module or product.

Answer (score 1):

You can add area paths to support teams and to group work items based on product, feature or buisness areas. Then, define area paths at the project level and assign them to a team under the team configuration. You can also create a hierarchy of area paths to support subcategories within categories.

Each team has access to a number of Agile tools as described in [About teams and Agile tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/about-teams-and-settings?view=azure-devops). Each tool references the team's default area path(s). Most teams choose one area path and several iteration paths to support their work tracking activities. However, to support other scenarios, it's possible for teams to choose several area paths to appear on their backlogs and boards.

New projects contain a single, root area that corresponds to the project name. A team is created with the same project name and the root area path is assigned to that team. 
To understand how the system uses area paths, see [About area and iteration paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/about-areas-iterations?view=azure-devops).

You can quickly generate queries to view the progress based on an area path. For example, [visualize progress of work items that are assigned to each team's area path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/charts?view=azure-devops), as shown in the following stacked bar chart. Choose Node Name to get the leaf node of the Area Path.

[image]

You can use [tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/add-tags-to-work-items?view=azure-devops) to differentiate and quickly filter the product backlog or a work item.

Document Reference - [Area Paths and team assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-area-paths?view=azure-devops)

[Azure DevOps REST API Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=vsts-rest-5.0) for automation.

Hope the above information helps for you to create area paths with regards to each team you might have based on there business areas. Team should be able to move items from one area path to another based on your requirement. You can visualize the based on area path and tags.

If you have specific idea for the product , you can always share your feedback [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/visual-studio-team-services.html?type=idea) for the concerned product team to look into.